# Entity Framework connection string for sql client

Tags: entity-framework

I have an EF connection string defined in my `web.config` but for some reason I would like to use .NET SQL Client. Is there a way to use the EF connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
// Add a reference at the top of your code file

using System.Configuration;

// Within the code body set your variable

string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: but can sql client use the same connection string? I mean does the format not matter?

Comment: Thats ok. I'm asking you to post both connection strings. I believe they are same. Please post if different.\